# What is Speedo Steve in a column?

Tags: meaning

> Then there’s the new avalanche of off-sites, multiday tests of togetherness in which you might be expected to hash out a new sales strategy one minute and the next brave the hotel pool with Speedo Steve and other colleagues, perhaps in a swimsuit of your own.

It is from [the Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/youre-good-at-your-job-but-are-you-fun-enough-11675286566?st=tov5c5ixyo06otc&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink). I presume the whole meaning as that some enjoyable things happen.

What does Speedo Steve mean? And why should someone brave(verb?) the hotel pool with it (or him)? I know that Speedo is a famous swimsuit brand.

Comment: 'Speedo Steve' is probably a derisive name for a man who shows off at a swimming pool. One can 'brave' (verb) something daunting or hazardous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a former New Yorker and used to this type of sardonic usage in news writing of a certain caliber. They are trying to be funny.  It requires a "deep dive" (pun intended) into English-speaking office culture.

**In offices, some people are given nicknames**. The reference here is this:
Most men in the US do not wear Speedo swimming briefs. **Speedo is a brand of swimwear for swimming as a sport.** *This is unlike Europe where briefs like this are more common.*

[image]

So, in an American office, calling someone Speedo Steve is just a way to refer to the guy who tries to get attention or will get it (anyway) by **wearing what usually in the States is only worn by competitive swimmers.** The Speedo wearer will definitely stand out at a pool party...

I have to say that it could me a moment to get this.

**Another point**: In the TV show called The Office (originally a British show created by Ricky Gervaise, with the same name), there are a bunch of nicknames for those who worked at Dunder Mifflin (a paper company), itself a funny name that actually evoked the book publisher Houghton Mifflin.

For example:

> **Michael Scotch**, Ping, Michael **Klump**,
> **Blindguy** McSqueezy, **Caleb Crawdad**. **Prison Mike**. Orville **Tootenbacher**

[The Office nicknames](https://www.reddit.com/r/DunderMifflin/comments/a3bmqi/a_complete_list_of_aliases_nicknames_of_office/)

To brave a place: have the courage to go to a place. Here, it's meant to be funny.

Comment: I have a pair of Speedo brand shorts that are not like that picture; they are about as long as boxer shorts and in a rather natty red and green plaid pattern. The wearers of the type in the picture are laughed at by many Brits and sometimes called 'budgie smugglers'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Speedo *briefs* are not Speedo **trunks** or **swim(ming) shorts**. Please try not to naysay my answer. In the States, Speedo is really the market leader for these briefs. What's in my picture are *not shorts*, which is the whole point of my post. I get tired of pissing contexts. [sic]

Comment: I must try to remember not to naysay your answers, and will try very hard not to do so in future.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I can actually see you saying that with a straight face. And I therefore thank you for the gesture. :) This afternoon, I shall be interpreting virtually in the field of robotics for a lawyer and his client and thus must raise my concentration gate.

Comment: You are right about my face. Good luck and have a nice weekend!

Comment: I have a pair of Speedo trunks - which are definitely ***trunks***, not ***briefs***. But my uptick for your comment was purely for ***budgie smugglers*** (I've heard it once or twice before, but it still creased me up! :) Of course, it's completely irrelevant to OP's question exactly how "Speedo Steve" advertises his "endowments" (maybe we're just supposed to gawp at his awesome biceps or his "six-pack"). He's just someone else on the same "residential course" as you, that you might interact with (gladly or otherwise) in ways that have no connection to the actual course you're [both] on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  **It is about the fact that in American culture, people would make fun of a guy wearing that type of Speedo briefs**.

Answer (score 5):

**Speedo Steve** is just a nickname for a generic male wearing tight bathing trunks (not necessarily Speedos). Possibly suggesting that he is showing off his physique.
To brave something is defined by the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brave) as

> to deal with an unpleasant or difficult situation.

Again the writer is being humorous,  suggesting the swimming with Speedo Steve and your other colleagues is possibly an uncomfortable situation. Something out of your comfort zone, but which has to be endured as part of "team building".

Comment: It is not uncomfortable; it is funny and the other office workers would be snickering.

Comment: @Lambie I was thinking more of in terms of embarrassment caused by appearing in front of your colleagues in a bathing costume when they are usually dressed in formal office attire. Think seeing your manager in his Speedos and being seen by him in yours.

Comment: Peter, hate to break it to ya, but I'm a woman, not a man. :)

Comment: @Lambie Oops sorry! Put it down to an inaccuracy of phrasing rather than an assumption of your gender .  But I believe Speedo make swimming costumes for both sexes. In any case it is possible that some women would feel even more uncomfortable mixing with her male colleagues when they are all dressed only in swimming costumes. Particularly if there were issues of seniority or worse harassment.

Comment: I don't think we *have* to assume that "Speedo Steve" is the reason addressee might need to be "brave". Residential courses tend to run all year round, and not all hotel pools are indoor and/or heated. So Speedo Steve might be a very welcome ***ally*** helping you find the resolve to venture out for a quick ***cold, refreshing*** dip before the next course presentation.

Comment: Speedo makes bathing costumes (swimsuits or bathing suits) of all several types for men, women and children. BUT, the men's briefs for sports' swimmers is what is meant here. The joke here is about going to a pool. If all the office people go to the pool, and **one guy** wears a Speedo, that's the joke., It's not about feeling uncomfortable about being in swimwear per se.